# How I can get all links from HTML using watir?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I need to get array of all links on HTML page. How I can do this?

Comment: Glad that Justin was able to answer your question, but did you search (Google and StackOverflow) before you posted?  This is a very common goal for Ruby testers.

Answer (score 7):

You can get a collection of all links on the page by doing:

```
browser.links
```

or

```
browser.as
```

You can then do things like:

```
#Get all link texts as an array
browser.links.collect(&:text)

#Click the second link
browser.links[1].click
```

If you really want the links as an array, you can use the `to_a` method (though I cannot recall a time where this has been needed):

```
browser.links.to_a
```